# Using korn shell to compare local and remote MD5 over sftp

Tags: ksh, aix, sftp, hashsum

I am in need of creating and checking checksums between a local file, and the remote file I just pushed.  If the MD5 checks, continue, else break.  This needs to be in KORN shell scripting because we are using AIX machines.

here's the code I have so far:

```
for file in <<Directory>>; do
    -- Get MD5 of local file
    LOCALMD5=!chsum "$(basename "$file")"
    sftp <<USER>>@<<IP>> <<EOF
    PUT file <<SFTP OUTPUT FOLDER>>
    REMOTEMD5= <<<COMMAND HERE>>>>  <<--- Which command?
    IF [[LOCALMD5!=REMOTEMD5]]; THEN
        RETURNVALUE = -1
        BREAK
done

print RETURNVALUE
```

How do I get the remote MD5 checksum?

Comment: Are you actually calling `cksum`, or is `chsum` some other local utility/function/wrapper?

Comment: this is new code, so we are using cksum right now.

Comment: New to Korn Scripting

Comment: do you have `csum` available? (AIX 7's supports MD5)

Comment: do you have ksh93 available? (for array support)

Comment: great questions.  assume I do.

Comment: Can you ssh to the remote site and run checksum commands?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you say: *the remote file I just pushed*, the probability of any file difference is extremely low over sftp (based on ssh code). As low as (in the order of) the probability that the md5 of two different files have the same hashsum.

And, the short answer is:

An [sftp session doesn't allow remote execution of commands](https://askubuntu.com/a/973837/772601). So, if you cannot ssh to the machine, you don't have a way to remotely run md5.

So, to check a remote file you will need to read it back, which, IMhO seems silly.

---

The only way is, then, to do:

```
ssh user@remote-dns-name
```

And once in the shell it opens, execute the [command(s) you need](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21496703):

```
$ cd path/to/file
$ csum -h MD5 >MD5-hashsum-filename
```

And then, copy the file created back to the local machine.

Comment: Thanks much.  guess that's the way I have to go.