# setting a remote stdout into local KORNSHELL variable

Tags: shell-script, shell, aix

I'm writing a script.  The idea is to compare MD5 checksums between a local file and a remote one.

The local file checksum is saved into a local variable:

```
LOCALMD5=!chsum "$(basename "$file")"
```

I was just recommended this script to get the md5 checksum on the remote file. do:

```
ssh user@remote-dns-name 
cd path/to/file
csum -h MD5 >MD5-hashsum-filename
```

Assuming I can successfully run `csum` in an ssh environment, how do I set the output of that command back to a local variable that I can use into the future?

Comment: since you're comparing checksums, I think it'd make more sense to `ssh user@remote "cd /path; csum ..." > /path/to/local/file`; and then `csum -i /path/to/local/file`.

Comment: Thanks Jeff.  This is a bit confusing for me here.  how do I actually perform the check in the script?

Comment: I'm considering writing up an answer to your [previous question](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/474645/using-korn-shell-to-compare-local-and-remote-md5-over-sftp), though you seem to have accepted an intermediate answer already.

Comment: well, you did answer it.  I'm generating questions as the situation pops up.  Besides, you get more points.  :)

Comment: well, I thought it was you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to just capture the STDOUT of `csum` through `ssh`.

To get the full output of `csum`, with both the hash and the filename:

```
bash-$ remoteMD5=$(ssh user@remote-dns-name "csum -h MD5 /full/path/to/file")
bash-$ echo $remoteMD5
723fc34e606a4d0002fe86f417be5f56 /full/path/to/file
```

Or you could return just the hash:

```
bash-$ remoteMD5=$(ssh user@remote-dns-name "csum -h MD5 /full/path/to/file" | awk '{print \$1}'")
bash-$ echo $remoteMD5
723fc34e606a4d0002fe86f417be5f56
```